# Is it legal to pass a newly constructed object by reference to a function?

Tags: c++

Specifically, is the following legal C++?

```
class A{};

void foo(A*);
void bar(const A&);

int main(void)
{
    foo(&A());  // 1
    bar(A());  // 2
}
```

It appears to work correctly, but that doesn't mean it's necessarily legal.  Is it?

*Edit - changed `A&` to `const A&`*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1: Taking the address of a temporary is not allowed. Visual C++ allows it as a language extension (language extensions are on by default).

2: This is perfectly legal.

Comment: it's forbidden to take the address of an rvalue, not a temporary specifically. that's why this is forbidden; `A()` returns an rvalue.

Comment: @underscore_d True - I used the informal term 'temporary', more specifically an unnamed temporary variable, and, as you rightly say, an rvalue. If we're being picky, `A()` doesn't 'return' an rvalue (constructors don't have return values), it's a prvalue expression.

Comment: Good catch - it's too easy to reflexively think of constructors as function calls.

Answer (score 10):

No, it's against the standard to pass a non-const reference to a temporary object. You can use a const reference:

```
class A{};

void bar(const A&);

int main(void)
{
    bar(A());  // 2
}
```

So while some compliers will accept it, and it would work as long as don't use the memory after the semicolon, a conforming compiler will not accept it.

Answer (score 6):

*foo* is not allowed in fully standard compliant C++, whereas *bar* is okay. Though chances are, *foo* will compile with warning, and *bar* may or may not compile with a warning as well.

*A()* create a temporary object, which unless bound to a reference (as is the case in *bar*), or used to initialize a named object, is destroyed at the end of the full expression in which it was created. A temporary created to hold a reference initializer persists until the end of its reference's scope. For the case of *bar*, that's the function call, so you can use *A* inside *bar* perfectly safely. It is forbidden to bound a temporary object (which is a rvalue) to a non-const reference. It is similarly forbidden to take the address of a rvalue (to pass as argument to initialize *A* for *foo*).

Comment: Needs some refactoring to make clear the scope enhancing abilities of a referene on a temporary variable.

Comment: This is the superior answer because it gets it right that what's forbidden is taking the address of an rvalue - not a temporary specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is yes.

If the object is received by function as const reference parameter - as you have modified `bar(const A&)` method, then it's totally legal. The function can operate on the object, but the object will be destructed after the function call (address of temporary can be taken, but shall not be stored and used after the function call - see reason below).

The `foo(A*)` is legal too because the temporary object is destroyed at the end of fullexpression. However most of the compiler will emit warning about taking address of temporary.

The original version of `bar(A&)` shall not compile, it's against the standard to initialize a non-const reference from a temporary.

> **C++ standard chapter 12.2**
>
> 3 [...] Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the fullexpression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. [...]
>
> 4 There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the fullexpression. The first context is when an expression appears as an initializer for a declarator defining an object. In that context, the temporary that holds the result of the expression shall persist until the object’s initialization is complete. [...]
>
> 5 The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object to a subobject of which the temporary is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except as specified below. A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctorinitializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits. A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full expression containing the call.
> A temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) persists until the function exits.

A **fullexpression** is an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression.

Comment: No, `foo( &A() )` is _not_ legal because `A()` is an rvalue, and you cannot take the address of an rvalue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2985578/2757035

Answer (score 1):

Those A objects will only exist until execution reaches the semicolon.  So, the calls are safe, but don't try to save the pointer and use it later.   Also, the compiler may require bar take a const reference.

Comment: `foo( &A() ) might be "safe", _if_ it compiles. It's not valid C++.

Answer (score 0):

It looked lke it would work, but it did not compile with g++ with the Wall option, here is what I get:

```
michael@hardy-lenovo:~/Desktop$ g++ -Wall a.cpp
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:michael@hardy-lenovo:~/Desktop$ g++ -Wall a.cpp
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:8: warning: taking address of temporary
a.cpp:9: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘A&’ from a temporary of type ‘A’
a.cpp:4: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void bar(A&)’
michael@hardy-lenovo:~/Desktop$
```

Looks like you will need to use a constant reference.

Comment: But the fact that both MSVC and g++ issue warnings for (1) suggests that it may be not be 100% legal.  Do you have a section of the C++ standard ti cite?

Answer (score -1):

It is legal. We use it sometime to provide a default value which we might want to ignore.

```
int dosomething(error_code& _e = ignore_errorcode()) {
    //do something
}
```

In the above case it will construct an empty error code object if no `error_code` is passed to the function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your ignore_errorcode() returns an error_code object with some more lifetime than an object created by a default constructor...

Answer (score -1):

for //2 you need a const reference

for //1 I think it's legal but useless

Comment: No, `foo( &A() )` is _not_ legal because `A()` is an rvalue, and you cannot take the address of an rvalue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2985578/2757035

Answer (score -2):

Perfectly legal.

The object will exist on the stack during the function call, just like any other local variable as well.