# Pass temporary object to function that takes pointer

Tags: c++, function, temporary

I tried following code :

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string f1(string s)
{
   return s="f1 called";
}

void f2(string *s)
{
   cout<<*s<<endl;
}

int main()
{
   string str;
   f2(&f1(str));
}
```

But this code doesn't compile.
What I think is : f1 returns by value so it creates temporary, of which I am taking address and passing to f2.
Now Please explain me where I am thinking wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unary `&` takes an lvalue (or a function name).  Function `f1()` doesn't return an lvalue, it returns an rvalue (for a function that returns something, unless it returns a reference, its return value is an rvalue), so the unary `&` can't be applied to it.

Comment: But I am able to use f1() like this :
f1(str)="happy";
Here I am using temporary as l-value.

Comment: Happy Mittal, the word lvalue may be a little confusing -- it no longer means "a value that can stand on the left side of an assignment". when you use the `=` operator, you are in fact calling a member function of the string object. You are allowed to use members of rvalues.

Comment: So what would happen if string had an explicit operator& {return this;}?

Comment: @user:  The temporary returned by `f1()` exists until the end of the full expression in which it is created; this means its lifetime is effectively from when `f1()` returns it until the moment that `f2()` returns.  So, I'd think an overloaded unary `&` would allow you to obtain a pointer to the temporary object (though it's somewhat terrifying and horrible to think about).

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to create (and pass) a pointer to a temporary object, assuming that you know what you are doing. However, it should be done differently.

A function with return value of non-reference type returns an *rvalue*. In C++ applying the built-in unary operator `&` to an rvalue is prohibited. It requires an lvalue.

This means, that if you want to obtain a pointer to your temporary object, you have to do it in some other way. For example, as a two-line sequence

```
const string &r = f1(str);
f2(&r);
```

which can also be folded into a single line by using a cast

```
f2(&(const string &) f1(str));
```

In both cases above the `f2` function should accept a `const string *` parameter. Just a `string *` as in your case won't work, unless you cast away constness from the argument (which, BTW, will make the whole thing even uglier than it already is). Although, if memory serves me, in both cases there's no guarantee that the reference is attached to the original temporary and not to a copy.

Just keep in mind though creating pointers to temporary objects is a rather dubious practice because if the obvious lifetime issues. Normally you should avoid the need to do that.

Comment: I have a constructor that requires a pointer, which it uses only within the constructor. In a child class, I needed to pass the result of a function into this constructor in the preamble. The function returned a value, I needed a pointer, I needed a single line way to do this. This was exactly the solution I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't compile because `f1` has a parameter and you're not passing any.

Additionally, the value returned from a function is an rvalue, you can't take its address.

Comment: Oh...My bad.
But it is still giving warning : "taking address of temporary"

Comment: Happy Mittal, yes, because it is an rvalue. Imagine the function returning an `int` instead of a `string`, it may be more obvious -- the value being returned need not have any corresponding memory location.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    string str;
    string str2 = f1(str); // copy the temporary
    f2(&str2);
}
```

Comment: That's one unnecessary copy. (_If you don't mind needlessly copying strings, why bother with C++ at all?_) If you bind an rvalue to a `const` reference, the rvalue's lifetime will be extended to the end of the reference's lifetime. So `const std::string& str2=f1(str);` is what you want.

Comment: @sbi: My example, like his, is much simpler than any real-world code.

Comment: Note that your answers are to teach people how to do things they don't know yet. Even though you only omit something because it's not relevant to your argument, others might still pick up a wrong habit from it.

Comment: @sbi Copy elision probably makes the two proposed pieces of code the same, and this one looks less obscure. Yours more directly answers the question, but I'm not sure the right question was asked. ;)

Comment: @underscore_d: If you think `const` references are obscure, you have some catching up to do. `:)`

Comment: @sbi Obscure was the wrong word of course. I meant slightly more obfuscated. :P But I'm programming in C at the moment, so _any_ C++ looks clearer to me...