# Passing a pointer to temporary object

Tags: c++, pointers, temporary-objects

We know that we can pass temporary objects to functions by const reference, like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int _b = 0) 
    {
        b = _b;
    }

    int b;
};

void foo(A& a) {printf("%d", a.b);}
void cfoo(const A& a) {printf("%d", a.b);}

int main(void)
{
    //foo(A(4)); doesn't compile
    cfoo(A(5));
}
```

but what about passing by pointer?
why does this compile?

```
void pfoo(A* pa) {pa->b = 19;}

int main(void)
{
    pfoo(&A(5));
}
```

Comment: You are just passing the pointer to a variable created on the stack. Its just an address in memory which works so long as that memory is valid. 

I am not quite sure what the issue is here. Why do you think the reference should work and not the pointer?

Comment: Can you *please* change the words "anonymous variable" to "temporary". Think of it as a way to (a) save on typing, and (b) accurately describe the actual state of the data being hurled around). And `foo(A(5))` fails to compile because the parameter decl is a non-const reference, and therefore cannot be fed a **temporary**. Sending the *address* of a temporary should have at-least-warned you was wrong. If it didn't, you need to crank up your compiler warnings or trash that compiler and get one that will warn you of such hideousness.

Comment: In gcc and clang `error: taking address of temporary`.  Although it can be forced to compile with `-fpermissive` and the address gives an answer.

Comment: @GlGuru `&A(5)` is an error, it is not "pointer to a variable created on the stack".  Rvalues cannot have their address taken.

Comment: Thank you, I stand corrected.

Comment: Thanks, I understand some of what you've said, and some I don't. Anyway I guess my compiler swallowed the error/warning, and that passing pointer to a temporary object is wrong/cannot be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass temporary object to function that takes pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985571/pass-temporary-object-to-function-that-takes-pointer)

Answer (score 4):

> but what about passing anonymous variables pointer? why does this compile?

You are probably using a compiler that does not honour C++ standard.

No address of an r-value (temporary) object can be taken. That should not compile.

---

However, `operator&` can be overloaded, so that it can be invoked on a temporary object, e.g.:

```
struct A
{
    A* operator&() { return this; }
};
```

---

In C++11 a temporary object can be bound to an r-value reference. After that r-value reference behaves like an l-value and hence the address of a temporary object can be taken:

```
struct A {};

void foo(A*);

void foo(A&& a) { foo(&a); }

int main() {
    foo(A{});
}
```