# Pass QDateTime as Pointer

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function

```
void func(QDateTime* date) {}
```

when i want to pass thw current date i need to do

```
QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc();
QDateTime *pnow = &now;
func(pnow);
```

is there a shorthand?

```
func(*QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc());
```

does not work

and

```
func(&QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc());
```

gives: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

Comment: One question: why?

Comment: because i want to be able to pass "null"

Comment: What is wrong with `QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc(); func(&now);`?

Comment: nothing... the now variable cannot be avoided completly?

Comment: @wutzebaer You can pass it by `const&` and a [default-constructed state](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#QDateTime) will mean null.

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicate, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985571/pass-temporary-object-to-function-that-takes-pointer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907846/passing-a-pointer-to-temporary-object, and probably others.

Comment: You may also want to consider `boost::optional`

Comment: A default-constructed QDateTime() is invalid (.valid() == false), there’s no need to pass a QDateTime by pointer, ever.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need the varaible to store the pointer unless you want to use it later for other purpose. You can write

```
QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc();
func(&now);
```

Comment: ok and the now variable cannot be avoided?