# Is it legal to hold reference/pointer to the return object value of a function?

Tags: c++

Is it legal to pass the return object of the function by value?
I have a function from `A::getA()` that returns an object by value.
Is it legal to reference this value in the same line, see the line
`b.processA(a.getA());`

Please see my code below:

```
class A
{
public:
    int a;
    std::list<int*> m_list;

    A(int a)
    {
        this->a =a;
    }

    A(A& _a)
    {
        this->a =_a.a;
        m_list.push_back(&a);
    }

    A getA()
    {
        A localA(20);
        localA.m_list.push_back(&localA.a);
        return localA;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    char b;

    B(char b)
    {
    }

    void processA(A& a)
    {
            a.a = 1;
            processA2(a);
    }

    void processA2(A& a)
    {
        a.a = 2;
    }
};

void main()
{
    B b('a');
    A a(11111);
    //************
    // IS THE FOLLOWING LINE LEGAL??
    // I mean, is it legal to pass the return object of the function by value
    //************
    b.processA(a.getA());
}
```

Comment: A link on why `void main` is bad: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: It is not legal to use `void main()`; you must use `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: it's illegal according to which state's law? :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
b.processA(a.getA());
```

No. It will not even compile. The reason is that`a.getA()` returns a temporary object, which cannot be bound to non-const reference type.

However, if you make the parameter const reference as:

```
void processA(A const & a)
```

then it is fine.

**Note**: MSVC++ provides temporary-object binding to non-const reference as extension. It is not Standard.

Comment: Note however that the code has more problems (`getA` indirectly creates a pointer to a stale object)

Comment: @bochaltura MSVS has an extension that lets you bind to a non-const reference. If you turn off language extensions, you'll get an error.

Comment: @bochaltura: that is an MSVC 'extension' to the C++ language.

Comment: @bochaltura: Read the **Note** in my answer.

Comment: Duplication of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84427/is-it-legal-to-pass-a-newly-constructed-object-by-reference-to-a-function?rq=1), I guess.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you are asking if:

```
X f();
void g(X& x);

g(f());
```

is legal or not?

As a safety precaution a noncost reference can't bind to a temporary.  So the above is not legal.

However the following is legal:

```
X f();
void g(const X& x);

g(f());
```

The temprary will survive until g returns.

The reason the first version is llegal is because any changes made by g will be discarded, so why would you want that?  It most likely indicates a logical error, so as a language design decision it was made a compile-time error.