# How to use uniform initialization for a pointer?

Tags: c++, initialization

For example, I have a class

```
struct A
{
    A(int i, double d) {...}
};
```

and a function with an argument A

```
void f(A a);
```

I can call the function by

```
f( { 1, 3.14 } );
```

If the function has an argument A*

```
void g(A* a);
```

How to make it call like

```
g( my_new{1, 3.14} ); // Note: no type A is shown here.
```

Or how to derive the type A here?

Comment: Just a guess as I can't try it now but maybe: `g( &({1, 3.14}) );`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84427/is-it-legal-to-pass-a-newly-constructed-object-by-reference-to-a-function might be of interest for you.

Comment: To initialize a pointer, you need to obtain an lvalue somewhere. So probably not.

Comment: This seems not possible, what do you what to achieve using this, may be you can get some help there.

Comment: Voting to close since it's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You can't take an address of a temporary "directly"...

You can't take an address of a temporary with `&`:

```
g(&({1, 3.14}));
```

as per:

> **§5.3.1/3**
>
> The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. **The operand shall be an lvalue or a qualified-id.**

(emphasis mine)

### ... but you can indirectly!

For example, you can use a function to extract the pointer to the temporary object:

```
A* fn(A&& a) {
    return std::addressof(a);
}
```

and use it as:

```
g(fn({1, 4.0}));
```

Note that `std::addressof` is necessary to avoid possible `operator&` overloading for the class `A`.
You could also extract it via a member function of the class `A` and probably many other ways.

<sub>**Why the sudden opinion change?** Well, I've [discussed it](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17366383#17366383) with other C++ haters and apparently it is possible and perfectly legal.</sub>

### What I'd recommend

I'd recommend for `g` to take a `const` reference instead:

```
void g(const A& a);
```

and then:

```
g({1, 3.14});
```

will work fine (assuming, of course, that the constructor is not explicit).

Comment: time ago I have seen a wonderful bug connected in extracting the pointer of a constant... in the function, getting an int *a in this case, non const as in this case, there was `*a++`. Guess what... passing "0" to the function resulted in "1" being used in place of "0" every time the "0" constant was used! So I'd say... "you can indirectly" but I strongly advice not to.

Comment: @Sigismondo I second that.